# Correctness of a zigzag algorithm to find the most similar vector in a bounded integer lattice

Tags: algorithm-analysis, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, cryptography, lattices

I am currently working on an integer lattice problem, called the "most similar vector problem," and wondering if can be solved correctly by a simple "zig-zagging" algorithm.

Given a real vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$, [the most similar vector problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212681/most-similar-vector-problem-on-an-integer-lattice) is to find a discrete vector $v$ from a **bounded** integer lattice $L \in \mathbb{Z}^n \cap [-10,10]^n$ that maximizes the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) between $u$ and $v$. That is,

$$v \in \text{argmax}_{w \in L} \frac{u.w}{\|u\|\|w\|}$$

In an earlier post on MathOverflow, someone proposed solving the most similar vector problem by ["zig-zagging" across the lattice](https://mathoverflow.net/a/212881/49673). Informally, this is a greedy algorithm that generates a sequence of lattice vectors $w^k$ by starting from the origin and taking steps of length one in the direction of $u$. On the $k^\text{th}$ iteration, the algorithm chooses $w^{k+1}$ as the most similar lattice vector that one unit away from $w^k$ in some dimension. The algorithm terminates in $K$ iterations after we hit the boundary of the lattice in each dimension.

Formally, the "zig-zagging" algorithm can be stated as follows:

> **INITIALIZATION**
>   $$\begin{align} 
> w^0 &\longleftarrow (0,\ldots,0) &\text{(starting point)} \\
> d &\longleftarrow \text{sign}(u) \in \{-1,0,1\}^n &\text{(step direction)} \\ 
> \mathcal{J} &\longleftarrow \big\{1,\ldots,n ~\big|~ d_j \neq 0 \big\} &\text{(set of dimensions in which steps can be taken)}    
> \end{align}$$
>
> **ALGORITHM**
>
> $\text{while }  \mathcal{J} \neq \emptyset$
>
> $$\begin{align}  
> j^* &\longleftarrow \text{argmax}_{j \in \mathcal{J}} \frac{u \cdot(w^k + d \cdot e_j)}{\|u\|\|w^k + d \cdot e_j\|} & \text{(step in dimension $j$ that yields $w^{k+1}$ most similar to $u$)} \\ 
> w^{k+1} &\longleftarrow w^k + d \cdot e_{j^*} \\
> \mathcal{J} &\longleftarrow \mathcal{J} \setminus \big\{1,\ldots,n ~\big|~ |w_j^{k+1}|=10
>  \big\} & \text{(remove coordinates at boundary from consideration)} \\  
> k & \longleftarrow k + 1 
> \end{align}$$

Here $e_j$ is a unit vector with 1 in the $j^\text{th}$ coordinate and 0 elsewhere.

Once the algorithm terminates, we can use the sequence of generated lattice points $w^1,\ldots,w^K$ to find the most similar vector, $v$ as:

$$v \in \text{argmax}_{k=1,\ldots,K} \frac{u.w^k}{\|u\|\|w^k\|}$$

**My question is as follows:** Does the zig-zagging algorithm described above produce the most similar vector? If so, how can I prove it? If not, is there a counter example?

Comment: I think your algorithm formalization has some issues.   What does $w^k+d_j$ mean?  $w^k$ is a vector, but $d_j$ is a scalar.  I'm guessing you mean to use $w^k+x$ where $x$ ranges over all vectors that are zero in all but one position, say $x_j\ne 0$, and $x_j=d_j$.  Perhaps edit the question?

Comment: Your problem looks similar to the [Closest Vector Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Closest_vector_problem_.28CVP.29) (CVP), which is known to be NP-hard.  Have you tried looking for a reduction from CVP or SVP or some similar standard lattice problem, to see if you can show your problem is NP-hard?  The main difference is cosine distance instead of Euclidean distance.

Comment: [Also posted on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/218736/37212).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for letting me know. Sorry about the double posting - I was not aware that I could migrate the question between sites. That said, the question is now effectively migrated since the version on MathOverflow is closed.

Comment: @D.W. You're right the problem is very similar to the SVP/CVP. I looked into equivalences after posting the resource request but they did not seem promising. Part of the issue is that the cosine distance is scale-invariant / not a proper distance metric. The bound is also somewhat important here -- the zig-zagging algorithm is $O(Mn)$, where $M$ is the length of the boundary, so if the algorithm is correct, then I don't think that a reduction is possible, right?

Comment: That's right.  I was thinking that if you could prove your problem is NP-hard too, then you could draw the inference that the zig-zag algorithm is most likely not correct.  P.S. Another thing you could try is to implement the zig-zag algorithm and execute it on some random inputs and see if it gives you the correct answer in every case; i.e., try randomly searching for counterexamples.